# Yup validation doesn't work when use not(!) in matches function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

I have a project with React and next js. I use formik for handling my forms and Yup for validations
I have an input and I want perform some validations on it.

1. this field must be required so if user don't enter any information I show this message => Required
2. this field should not contain any numbers otherwise I Show this message => Wrongggg
3. this field must only contain Persian characters otherwise I Show this message => only Persian chars

this is my schema

```js
 Yup.string()
            .required("Requiredddd")
            .matches(!/\d/, 'Wrongggg'),
            .matches(/^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/, 'Only persian chars')
```

But in this case condition number 2 always Considered wrong.i think (!/\d/)  is wrong but I haven't any idea how can use matches function Negatively

Comment: Did you try `.matches(/\D/, 'Wrongggg')` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) you can use `.matches` using this shape:
`string.matches(regex: Regex, message?: string | function): Schema`. If you want to validate that the string doesn't contain numbers, instead of using `(!/\d/)` you should use `/\D+$/`.

```
 Yup.string()
            .required("Requiredddd")
            .matches(/\D+$/, 'Wrongggg')
            .matches(/^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/, 'Only persian chars')
```

See [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yup-when-tcc4xa)

Comment: this regex worked => /^([^0-9]*)$/ 
but it is not => /\D/

Comment: I updated my answer. I changed regex to `/\D+$/`

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with the `test()` function from Yup like the following:

```js
.test('name Your Test here', 'your validation message', (value) => !yourRegex.test(value))
```

I believe Yup should provide an opposite function for `.match()` since you don't always want to match, sometimes you want to test your value against the regex.